# Understanding Microsoft api response for office 365

Tags: json, api, fullcalendar, office365api

I'm trying to retreive information from MS Office 365 resource Calendar.

I use code shown below, and get a string returned. I would like to get it as a JSON feed. or array if JSON is not possible, as I plan to show the result on a  'fullcalendar'

Anyone know the trick.?

CODE:

```
$username = 'user@domain.com'; // User with delegate control.
$password = 'P@ssword';
$calendar = 'ressourceRoom@domain.com';

$URL = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/'.$calendar.'/calendarview?startDateTime=05/30/2016&endDateTime=06/13/2016';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$result= (curl_exec ($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
echo gettype($result)."<br /><br /><br />";
print_r($result);
```

RESULT (just beginning shown).:

```
string

 {"@odata.context":"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Users('room@domain.com')/CalendarView","value":[{"@odata.id":"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('room@domain.com')/Events('AAMkADBiMmM3NjE5LTUyMDUtNDY0Mi1hNjAyLTY2M2ZlYmM3OTkwOQBGAAAAAAAnzkQlYPmYQ4MtD6sjQqO8BwAaVyh143FwQZzopix2q_v7AAAAAAENAAAaVyh143FwQZzopix2q_v7AAAAAA0eAAA=')","@odata.etag":"W/\"GlcodeNxcEGc6KYsdqvr+wAAAAAMVg==\"","Id":"AAMkADBiMmM3NjE5LTUyMDUtNDY0Mi1jAyLTY2M2ZlYmM3OTkwOQBGAAAAAAAnzkQlYPmYQ4MtD6sjQqO8BwAaVyh143FwQZzopix2q_v7AAAAAAENAAAaVyh143FwQZzopix2q_v7AAAAAA0eAAA=","DateTimeCreated":"2016-06-06T12:07:57.398966Z","DateTimeLastModified":"2016-06-06T12:07:57.8833477Z","ChangeKey":"GlcodeNxcEGc6KYsdqvr+wAAAAAMVg==","Categories":[],"StartTimeZone":"Romance Standard Time","EndTimeZone":"Romance Standard Time","ResponseStatus":{"Response":"Accepted","Time":"2016-06-06T12:07:57.6489687Z"},"iCalUId" ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP response you get from the Office 365 REST already return the JSON format string. Based on the code, it seems you were developing with PHP. We need to convert the JSON format string to the JSON object via the library based on the language we were developing.

For example, we can use json_decode($string) to convert String into Array/Object in PHP. Refer to [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more detail.